# implementing a queue in a structured approach

Tags: c, queue, structure

For my structured approach to making a queue program, I am having a few problems with syntax and array indexs when it comes to pointers. I have marked the lines in which i am having trouble. Are these all a matter of not casting properly or is it a problem in terms of incorrect sytax?

```
    bool Enqueque(int** queue, int* front, int* rear, int* nElements, int* capacity, 
                  int userInput)
    {   

        //if there is no more space in the Queue
        if( *nElements == *capacity )
        {
            //update the capacity
            *capacity = *nElements * 2;

            //asked OS for more memory
            int* growQueue = (int*)malloc( (*capacity) * sizeof(int) );

            //error checking
            if(growQueue == NULL)
                return false;

            //take all the elements from the original queue and put into the bigger queue  
            for(int i = 0; i<*nElements; i++)
                growQueue[i] = (*queue)[i];
            free(*queue);
            *queue = growQueue;

            (*queue)[*nElements] = userInput;
            nElements++;

        }

        //if there is space in the queue
        else if(*nElements+1 > *capacity)
        {
            //if queue is empty
             if(front == NULL)
            {
                //front and rear are both pointers to the same element

                //These two lines are giving warnings
                //QueueLibrary.c:42:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from //integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  //           front = (*queue)[0];
                   ^
//QueueLibrary.c:43:18: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a //cast [-Wint-conversion]
             //rear = (*queue)[0];
                front = (*queue)[0];
                rear = (*queue)[0];



                (*queue)[0] = userInput;
                *nElements++;
                return true;
            }

             else if(*nElements >= 1)
             {
                 //move the userInput into the next available spot behind the 
                 //element after rear. 


//QueueLibrary.c:54:24: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size //[-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

              (*queue)[ (int)rear+1 ] = userInput;
                 (*queue)[ rear+1 ] = userInput;


//Array subscript is not an integer
                 rear = (*queue)[ rear+1 ];
                 return true;
             }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: In C in general there are very, very few cases where you ought to cast.

Comment: My recommendation is to remove all casts from your code. And then try fixing the warnings/errors the compiler issues differently. As it stands the casts just silence the compiler.

Comment: This `[ (int)rear+1 ]` for example is nonsense. `rear` is a pointer, which you most definitely do not want to use as an index to an array, which the compiler warned you about. The cast to an `int` just tells the compiler to "shutup", it does not fix the conceptual mistake.

Comment: Just replace `front = (*queue)[0];` with `front = queue[0];` for first warning and for second replace `(*queue)[ (int)rear+1 ] = userInput;` with `(*queue)[ (*rear)+1 ] = userInput;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that indexing an array with `array[index]` is equivalent to the operation `*(array + index)`. So let's go through what you're currently doing and why it's incorrect.

You have the variable `int **queue` which is a pointer to a pointer to an int. And you wanna extract the front and put it in the variable `int *front`. Your current approach is:

```
int *front = (*queue)[0];
```

and that translated using the equivalence from the top yields:

```
int *front = *((*queue) + 0)
```

the first `(*queue)` dereferences `queue` and yields an `int *`. You then add `0` to the `int *` which yields the same one, and then you dereference that. And what does dereferencing an `int *` yield?

**Hint**: you should not be assigning `int *foo` to an `int bar` directly with `foo = bar`.

Moving on to the other issues, array subscripts need to be integers. Looking at the type of `int * rear` should make it clear why doing `array[rear]` is issuing a warning.

If `int *rear` is supposed to **point** to the rear of the queue, why not just use it as your pointer instead of trying to index the queue with it?:)